# snap desktop-legacy interface - what privileged access does it leak? When can one disconnect it?

Tags: permissions, snap, privacy

I'm trying to take a more active role in ensuring the couple non-FOSS / untrusted but mandatory for work `snap`s I have installed are as confined as possible.

Looking at the `desktop-legacy` interface in particular, I see over at [the docs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/desktop-legacy-interface) that

> desktop-legacy allows privileged access to desktop legacy methods.

and

> If your snap has a graphical interface, you *should* [not must] connect to this interface. [while if you require say Chinese input it's mandatory (I do not require any of the listed examples)]

OK ... where am I supposed to find more information on this `"should"` ... **why** should I?  The ~manpage here says this is **privileged** access; I want to shut that off if it's not completely necessary to function.  But it's also risky / cat-and-mouse to change the setting without even being provided a reasonable description of *what kind of privileged* access it grants??

`snap`/`snapd` version `2.60.3`

Comment: There is a bit more information at: https://snapcraft.io/docs/desktop-interfaces. FOr a definitive answer, the snapd developers hang out in the snapcraft forum, and I have found them to be very responsive.